# Mocking Password facade in Laravel 4

Tags: php, testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to write phpunit tests for several controller actions. Everything seems to be fine except for mocking the Password facade.

One of the actions ("forgot password") goes like this:

```
if (Auth::check())
    //return a redirect since the user is already logged in

switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
{
    case Password::INVALID_USER:
        //return a redirect with error messages

    case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
        //return a redirect with success message flushed
}
```

Both Auth and Password are facades and come with Laravel by default.

Testing the `Auth::check()` part works just fine:

```
Auth::shouldReceive('check')->
    once()->
    andReturn(false);  //or true depending on my test case
```

But when I try the same attempt for `Password::remind()` call it doesn't work:

```
Password::shouldReceive('remind')->
    once()->
    andReturn(Password::INVALID_USER);
```

I get "SQLSTATE Access denied" exception meaning the app is trying to access the DB.

I also tried adding `with(array())` to my test or even binding a `Mockery::mock('\Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker')` - none of this helped.

How can this controller action be tested? Why is the Password facade different from Auth? What else should I try?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So I did some more searching, coding and investigating. I finally succeeded even though it should've worked the way I first intended.

I read in Laravel documentation that calling `Facade::shouldReceive('method')` should return a Mockery object. So I tried this in my test:

```
var_dump(get_class(Auth::shouldReceive('check')));
var_dump(get_class(Password::shouldReceive('remind')));
```

The first one was working as expected but the Password one was not. So after reading the web a little more, walking through Laravel facades and service providers I finally came up with Something.

I mock a PasswordBroker object (that's what Password facade is referring to anyway) and "introduce it" to IoC.

```
$this->authReminder = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker');
App::instance('auth.reminder', $this->authReminder);
```

And then later I use this object instead of Password facade like this:

```
$this->authReminder->
    shouldReceive('remind')->
    once()->
    andReturn(Password::INVALID_USER);
```

I know this doesn't answer why the facade mocking doesn't work with Password but at least after many hours of struggle I'm able to write the tests I need and continue with the project.